# Rearrange elements even and odd columns into one vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, columnsorting

I have a vector `A8` with two columns in it, here are two rows:

```
24.0192018449307    48.0192018449307
72.0576055347920    96.0576055347920
```

I want to create a new vector `A9` such that I get one column:

```
24.0192018449307
48.0192018449307
72.0576055347920
96.0576055347920
```

I have tried to use the following loop:

```
for j=1:4
   if mod(j,2)~=0
        A9(j)=A8(j,1);
   else 
        A9(j)=A8(j,2);
    end
end
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because `A8` has size 2x2, not 1x4.

But I can't figure it out.

I have tried using two loops:

```
for i=2;
  for j=1:4
      if mod(j,2)~=0
         A9(j)=A8(i,1);
      else
         A9(j)=A8(i,2);
      end
  end
end
```

But this gives me `A9` that has just the two elements of the second row repeated.

How can I rearrange this matrix?

Comment: What if you use two for loops but not nested. In the first, you assign to A9 The values of the first row A9(i)  =A8(0,i). And in the second for you assign it in this way  A9(i+2) =A8(1,i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A =   [24.0192018449307  48.0192018449307;
       72.0576055347920  96.0576055347920];
B = A.';
B = B(:)
```

Using the fact that MATLAB is column-based, and thus you can transpose your matrix and then use the colon operator to get a single vector.

By the way, using variable names like `A8` and `A9` smells really bad. Like dynamic variable naming bad. You'll run into loads of trouble later on by giving your variables dynamic names, or unclear names like that.